# other meaning of "Editorial"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following excerpt from *2 States: The Story of My Marriage* seems to use the word *editorial* in a way that doesn't match its definition:

> "That's not rasam. Whatever it is, it's definitely not rasam. And what's that, the dark yellow stuff?"
>
> "Sambhar", the mess worker growled.
>
> "Eew, looks disgusting! How did you make it?" she asked.
>
> "You want or not?" the mess worker said, more interested in wrapping up lunch than discussing recipes.
>
> While our lady decided, the two boys between us banged their plates on the counter. They took the food without **editorials** about it and left.

I thought that *editorial* means something related to publishing, and not related to food or cooking. The dictionaries I consulted seem to confirm this:

<sub>[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/editorial)</sub>

> *noun* 1. An article in a publication giving the opinion of its editors on a given topic or current event.

<sub>[Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/editorial?q=editorial)</sub>

> *noun* a newspaper article expressing the editor’s opinion on a topical issue
>   *adjective* relating to the commissioning or preparing of material for publication

These definitions look irrelevant to the context of the excerpt. Is there another dictionary that gives a more relevant definition? What does *editorial* mean in this context?

Comment: The key is the "giving opinion of its editors on a given topic".  It means they took the food without making any comments (giving opinions) about how disgusting it looks etc.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote. The meaning of "editorial" in the OP's example is metaphorical and idiomatic, & a non-native speaker can't be expected to understand it, even given the truncated definition of "editorial" as an expression of opinion. All this means is that the question should be redirected to ELL, but that's not open yet.

Answer (score 2):

In the excerpt, *editorial* is essentially being used as a synonym of *commentary*. It's odd that neither of the (generally good) dictionaries you looked in mention this metaphorical meaning. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/editorial?s=t) lists it as the third definition (emphasis mine):

> 1. an article in a newspaper or other periodical presenting the opinion of the publisher, editor, or editors.
> 2. a statement broadcast on radio or television that presents the opinion of the owner, manager, or the like, of the station or channel.
> 3. **something regarded as resembling such an article or statement**, as a lengthy, dogmatic utterance.

This usage of *editorial* usually has mildly uncomplimentary connotations, either because the statement of opinion was too lengthy, or because (as in the novel) it was being expressed in an unwelcome setting.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition you cite (from Wiktionary) is the relevant one.  As given, it refers to a written article, but the important piece is that it is *an expression of opinion on a given topic or current event*.

The girl very clearly expressed her opinion of the food ("Eew, looks disgusting!"), but the boys helped themselves and left without making any such commentary, which would have been an expression of their opinion on the current topic of food quality.  Thus, they took their food *with no editorials*.